# FFmpeg play video problem (too slow or too fast) : Playing video at right peed

Tags: ffmpeg, video-capture, video-processing

I can play video files with FFmpeg libary.( just implement tutorials about ffmpeg). But i have **a problem with "speed" of video files.** Sometimes ffmpeg play files too "quick" or to slow. So i ask my friends they say that i have to play video according to **"frame per second" (fps)** value of video file.  So my guestion

- Does ffmpeg give fps value of given video file? If so how can i get it?
- Or does any body know a method in which i can play video files at their right speeed using ffmpeg library?

Best Wishes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the video stream: VideoStream->r_frame_rate

Comment: fps == videoStream->r_frame_rate ( real frame rate)  .Ok. Thanks for your answer.